# How to count duplicated value as one per day?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, date, data-science

A cat shelter has many cats living there. Stray cat that frequently enters the shelter is given a collar containing an RF (Radio Frequency) tag. However, sometimes not all cats enter the cat shelter every day.

At the shelter door there is a sensor that detects a collar containing an RF tag when a cat enters. So, one cat can be detected several times in and out of the shelter per day.
This is sensor data (simplified).

```
data = {'Date': ['01-09-2022', '01-09-2022', '01-09-2022', '01-09-2022', '02-09-2022', '02-09-2022', '02-09-2022', '02-09-2022', '03-09-2022', '03-09-2022', '03-09-2022', '03-09-2022', '03-09-2022'],
        'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

The data like this

```
    Date        Name
0   01-09-2022  A
1   01-09-2022  A
2   01-09-2022  A
3   01-09-2022  A
4   02-09-2022  B
5   02-09-2022  C
6   02-09-2022  C
7   02-09-2022  B
8   03-09-2022  D
9   03-09-2022  C
10  03-09-2022  C
11  03-09-2022  D
12  03-09-2022  A
```

The question is, how do I know how many days a cat named "A" comes to the shelter per three days? (although the cat named "A" appears several times per day, it still counts as one).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to see how many times a cat in a day, and how many different days the cat entered.

```
print(ans.groupby(["Name", "Date"])["Date"].count())
```

You get an output like this:

```
Name  Date      
A     01-09-2022    4
      03-09-2022    1
B     02-09-2022    2
C     02-09-2022    2
      03-09-2022    2
D     03-09-2022    2
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Then, save this and check a cat that enters in different days.

```
df_count = ans.groupby(["Name", "Date"]).agg({"Date": "count"})
print(df_count.groupby("Name").count())
```

I think, this is the answer of your question.

```
      Date
Name      
A        2
B        1
C        2
D        1
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your desired output?

Doing `df[df['Name']=='A'].drop_duplicates()` you know how many days cat 'A' enter in the shelter

Comment: How drop_duplicates() can detect different day? The code just df['Name']=='A', but it can count cat just different day. By the way, i desired output can show number amount per three days, amount per week, amount per month.